# Hololens 2 - Is there a way for logging and see logs for Store Apps?

Tags: logging, uwp, hololens, microsoft-store

I searched this matter about logging in Hololens 2 App (I work on Unity), and I'm stuck about log management for Microsoft Store Apps.

So, I know how to write logs and see them via the Windows Device Portal on **sideload apps**, ok, but I struggle to find a way for writing logs and seeing them **when the apps are uploaded to the Microsoft Store.**

It seems very complicated, is there an Api like Serilog available? Or HockeyApp ? We can write logs to the App Center directly ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [Visual Studio App Center](https://appcenter.ms/). It supports Unity listed here: [App Center- Get Started with Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/unity). App Center will log the error in your app and you could check it in the App Center Portal.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I checked that solution, but it is not free or included in our current subscription. We already have an Azure subscription with many services, I was wondering if it could be possible to create an Application Insights with this subscription.

Also, we already have, by default, the Microsoft Partner Center where we can check the crash logs of the App. I thought about writing logs into that space, but I don't know if there is an Api that we could use to do that.

Comment: @GwenGuts There are UWP API that could allow you to send custom event to the Partner Center which could be seen in the Usage report. Please remember it doesn't recode error logs. You need to set the content for it. Please refer to this documnet:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/log-custom-events-for-dev-center

Comment: Ah, yes, it's a good news ! I'll test it, thanks

Comment: Another question, is there any additional fee for sending data through Api to the Partner Center ? I suppose you must not send too many data through this Api

Comment: @GwenGuts I have to say that there is no more API that could send data to the Partner Center. This API is used to send some custom event and is not suitable to send full trace.

Comment: @GwenGuts I've talked with app center guys, most of the features of App center is free like `Analytics & Diagnostics`. Mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/pricing#free-services

Comment: Ok, understood, thanks for all the details, we'll make some tests to see if we'll use that or use a custom solution